# Entity Framework Add and Remove items in collection efficiently

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have an entity with a child collection

given a list of ids => NewIdList I want to the items from Children that aren't in NewIdList and create new item for those ids that are in NewIdList but aren't in Children.

Excuse Psuedo Code :)

```
myEntity.Children = new [] {2, 3}

var newIdList = new [] {1, 2, 4, 5}

// Do Magic

myEntity.Children = new [] {1, 2, 4, 5}

// Note that '2' would not have a created date 
// or audit record as it was in the list before Do Magic occured
```

I'm planing on doing something like this

```
var newIdList = new [] {1, 2, 4, 5};
var childrenToRemove = myEntity.Children.Where(c=> !newIdList.Contains(c));
var childrenToAdd = newIdList.Where(c => myEntity.Children.Contains(c));

foreach(var cr in childrenToRemove){
    myEntity.Children.Remove(cr);
}

foreach(var ca in childrenToAdd ){
    myEntity.Children.Add(cr);
}
```

Is this the best way to achieve this...it feels kind of clumsy

Answer (score 1):

```
var list1 = new[] { 2, 3 };
var list2 = new[] { 1, 2, 4, 5 };

var excepts = list1.Except(list2);
var union = list1.Union(list2);
var newlist = union.Except(excepts);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", newlist));
```

Comment: Oh I see, that’s not helpful.